# Find the maximum of every column in HIVE without explicitly naming them

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

How could one find the maximum of every column in a table without explicitly naming them?

```
SELECT MAX(*) from table
```

doesn't work, returning the error message:

```
Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException 
The specified syntax for UDAF invocation is invalid.
```

Comment: No short-cut available, you'll have to do MAX() on each column.

Comment: You can add this as an answer and if nobody else knows otherwise I'll mark it as  accepted :)

Comment: You can write a script to read through table DDLs and generate the SQL which contains a max of each column in a single query and export them to a CSV/text file.

Comment: Yeah, I could think of a number of really complicated ways, but the goal would have been to have an one-liner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No short-cut available, you'll have to do `MAX()` on each column.